# What is probability that at least $2$ people have same birthday from group of $N$ people?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, permutations

Question is not that simple.

There are also leap year included.Leap year will be $366$ days and normal year will be $365$ days.

There is a statement in question that : there are exactly  $\lfloor{\dfrac{n}{4}}\rfloor$ people who born in leap year.

Now we have to find probability of at least $2$ people having same birthday from group of $N$ people .

Edit : sorry i forgot a word to add!

Any help or hints and calculation and edit in questions are appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: Hi,   Rather than reinvent the wheel, here's a link. I didn't check for correctness; use your judgment, or use Google for other links. Cheers!    http://www.efgh.com/math/birthday.htm   (Leap years ARE CONSIDERED in the latter part of the article.)

Comment: @mathguy i will check this link! If you find any better solution or article about this share it ! Thanks..

Comment: The leap day doesn't change the spirit of the question.  It just make the math tedious.  The answer is still $1 - P^N$ where P is is the probability that 2 people have different birthdays.  But P doesn't equal 364/365.  Instead P equals 364.25/365.25 (which in turn is [4.365.(4.364+1) + 4.365]/(4.365+1)^2 if you want to be utterly fussy).

Comment: A similar  question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744588/probability-of-same-birthday-variation) was asked yesterday. Turns out this is currently a question in an online contest.

Comment: @fleablood "The answer is still 1−P^N where P is is the probability that 2 people have different birthdays" No. You probably mean $1-P^{N-1}$ but even forgetting leap years this is wrong for every $N\geqslant3$, for example, if $N=3$, the answer is $1-(364/365)(363/365)$ not $1-(364/365)^2$.

Comment: Another approach could view the n people as two separate groups, x and y, where x is the number of people with birthdays not on a leap year, and y is the same except for leap years. Of course, this would be a more general case than what this problem is as you would solve for any values of x, y whereas there was originally a restriction.

Comment: Argh!  You're right. it's really late.

Comment: You also forgot to mention that you are a cheater in an ongoing competition

Comment: I was wondering about the insistence on the leap day.  Makes it tedious and, surprisingly, difficult but it doesn't make it interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rephrase the question.

> Find the probability that any $2$ people have their birthday in the same day of the year in a group $4n$ people, of which $n$ born were in the leap year and $3n$ people were born in the regular year.

The complement of the event "any 2 people have their birthday" is "all people have birthday on different days of the year".

Consider two mutually exclusive possibilites: $\mathcal{A}_1$ - one of these birthdays falls on "Feb. 29", and $\mathcal{A}_2$ -- none of these birthdays fall on the leap day.

The number of configurations of the second kind is
$$
   N\left(\mathcal{A}_2\right) = \prod_{k=1}^{4 n} \left( 365 - (k-1) \right)
$$
and the number of configurations of the first kind is
$$
   N\left(\mathcal{A}_1\right) = n \prod_{k=1}^{4 n-1} \left( 365 - (k-1) \right)
$$
The total configuration size is $N_T=366^n 365^{3n}$, hence the probability of having no birthday duplicates is

$$
   p_c = \frac{ N\left(\mathcal{A}_1\right) +  N\left(\mathcal{A}_2\right)}{N_T}
$$

Here is a confirmation in *Mathematica*:

```
(* computed probability expression *)
p[n_Integer] = (Product[365 - (k - 1), {k, 1, 4 n}] + 
     n Product[365 - (k - 1), {k, 1, 4 n - 1}])/(366^n 365^(3 n));

(* simulation result *) 
In[45]:= With[{n=7,reps=10^8},
   Sum[Boole[DuplicateFreeQ[Join[
       RandomChoice[Range[1,366],n],
       RandomChoice[Range[1,365],3n]]]],{k,1,reps}]/reps]//N

Out[45]= 0.34599694

In[53]:= N[p[7]]

Out[53]= 0.3460041650022472

(* verify that computed value belongs to the sampling 
    confidence interval *)
In[55]:= With[{pSample = Out[45], pExpected = p[7]},
 IntervalMemberQ[
  Interval[pSample + {-1, 1} Sqrt[(pSample (1 - pSample))/10^8]], 
  pExpected]]

Out[55]= True
```

Answer (score -1):

Suppose we find the negation.
$p'(n)$ - is the probability when there is no two person with equal birthday.
$$p'(n) = (1-\frac{1}{365})(1 - \frac{2}{365})\cdots (1-\frac{n}{365}) = \frac{365!}{365^{n}(365-n)!}$$ (suppose we choose we choose one person from group, then choose another one with different birthday and continue this before n)

So the answer is: $$1-p'(n)$$ and it's ~$\frac{1}{2}$, when $n=23$

UPD : the probability of choosing person with leap year birthday is $s(n) = \frac{\lfloor  {\frac{N}{4}}\rfloor }{N}$ so the total probability will be :
$$(1-s(n))p_{365}(N-\lfloor \frac{N}{4}\rfloor) + s(n)p_{366}(\lfloor \frac{N}{4}\rfloor)$$ where $p_{365}(n)$ is probability for normal year

Comment: What about n/4 people who's birthday in leap year?

Comment: @PoojanPatel what does it mean $N$ in your task ?

Comment: We have to find 2 people having same birthday from group of N people.

Comment: @PoojanPatel this is the same.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem read about this

Comment: There is a statement in question that : there are exactly ⌊N/4⌋ people who born in leap year in group of N. So there N-⌊N/4⌋ people who is in normal year and⌊N/4⌋  in leap year.

Comment: @PoojanPatel missed that

Comment: So you should modify the task so: the probability of choosing the leap-year-man is : p~1/4 and another p'~3/4, now rewrite the formula for leap year and normal year , after add two probability

Comment: Openspace: Time to delete your answer - for some reason you have chosen to disregard the question the OP asked, and when he pointed this out to you, you continued with your nonsense. The most elegant solution is to delete your answer, which will also remove all the comments.

Comment: @mathguy I just try to help him to make the answer by himself

Comment: @mathguy see my upper comment